# FTP permission denied using php script

Tags: php, ftp, permissions

I have a problem with my ftp account. Here is the code I have written to connect to my FTP and create a folder:

```php
<?php 
$ftp_server = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$ftp_username = 'xxxxxxxx';
$ftp_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

// try to create directory $path
$path = '/2/7/7';
if(ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $path)) {
    echo 'done';
    die();
}
echo 'error';
?>
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

> Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Permission denied

When I use filezilla or another ftp manager application I can create a folder easily but the problem occurs while using a script to handle it. I told to my network administrator to make sure if the account has read and write permissions. They say that read and write permissions have been already set. I guess that it probably needs execute permission as well which might not be set.

Is there any way to check the permission using php script? I also tried to check the folder permission using filezilla but it shows something like this:

[image]

Comment: Does the path '/2/7 already exist? ftp_mkdir cannot make directories recursively (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php look at the first comment).

Comment: no, there is not exists but my script was working on the server for a couple of weeks. I got the error recently and I don't know what happened while I have not changed anything on the code.

Comment: Maybe at first it was creating a new directory when the lower levels already existed... When do these numbers change?

Comment: If the `/2/7` does not exist, it's clearly the problem. It probably existed when your script was still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution it works [recursive-ftp-make-directory](http://sameerparwani.com/posts/recursive-ftp-make-directory-mkdir)

> ```
> // recursive make directory function for ftp
> function make_directory($ftp_stream, $dir)
> {
> // if directory already exists or can be immediately created return true
> if (ftp_is_dir($ftp_stream, $dir) || @ftp_mkdir($ftp_stream, $dir)) return true;
> // otherwise recursively try to make the directory
> if (!make_directory($ftp_stream, dirname($dir))) return false;
> // final step to create the directory
> return ftp_mkdir($ftp_stream, $dir);
> }
>
> function ftp_is_dir($ftp_stream, $dir)
> {
> // get current directory
> $original_directory = ftp_pwd($ftp_stream);
> // test if you can change directory to $dir
> // suppress errors in case $dir is not a file or not a directory
> if ( @ftp_chdir( $ftp_stream, $dir ) ) {
> // If it is a directory, then change the directory back to the original directory
> ftp_chdir( $ftp_stream, $original_directory );
> return true;
> } else {
> return false;
> }
> }
> ```

don't forget to add `$dir='2/3/4/5/6'` for new recursively directory!